# Обернуть все что идет после div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется div, после которого идет текст и другие элементы.

```html
<div class="block">Some text</div>
<hr>
More text
<br>
Again more text
```

Как можно обернуть все, то что идет после div.block, включая hr и br в div.another__block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $b = $('.block')
var $c = $b.parent().contents()
$b.after($('<div>').html($c.slice($c.index($b) + 1)))
```

```css
.block + div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">Some text</div>
<hr>
More text
<br>
Again more text
```

```js
var $b = $('.block')
var $c = $b.parent().contents()
$c.slice($c.index($b) + 1).wrapAll('<div>')
```

```css
.block + div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">Some text</div>
<hr>
More text
<br>
Again more text
```

Comment: у jquery ж wrap есть

Comment: вернее wrapAll.

Comment: @Grundy, ага, работает. Дополнил. Но вообще, интереснее как-то в строчку извернуться, а у меня не придумывается. Даже с wrapAll.

Comment: я еще думал `nextAll` мог бы помочь, тогда красиво было бы: `$b.nextAll().wrapAll(...)`, но он только элементы берет, а текстовые ноды - нет

Comment: @Grundy, ага, я про него тоже думал, но он не подходит :(

Answer (score 4):

```js
var b = document.querySelector('.block')
var d = document.createElement('div')

while (b.nextSibling) {
  d.appendChild(b.nextSibling)
}

b.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', d)
```

```css
.block + div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Some text</div>
<hr>
More text
<br>
Again more text
```